# Install python package with Anaconda from local file, ImporError

Tags: python, linux, package, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) on my remote Linux server (Red Hat 4.4.7-1). Since I don't have sudo permission, the admin created `/usr/local2` folder and granted me with full permission on it.  After the installation, the python runs fine.

```
$ which python
/usr/local2/anaconda2/bin/python
```

The problem is installation of packages locally via `conda install`.
Now that the Linux server has internet connection restriction, and I have to use `conda install` to build from local package file. Take `pyodbc` for example...

```
$ conda install  pyodbc-3.0.10-py27_1.tar.bz2
```

No error message.

When I run python, and try to load the `pyodbc` library, it complains importError

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The problem is the `pyodbc.so` file actually is in the path.
Conda list shows the `pyodbc` package.

```
$ conda list
pygments                  2.1.3                    py27_0
pylint                    1.6.4                    py27_1
pyodbc                    3.0.10                   py27_1    file:///home/username/Downloads
pyopenssl                 16.2.0                   py27_0
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py27_0
```

I have read it might be related to LD_LIBRARY_PATH issue, but how do I set it given my case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: if I only had full access to my home folder, I am sure I would still be able to install full package of Anaconda 3 in my home folder. I don't know what sort of restriction you have on internet access but usually you run a script you download from the website and follow simple routine. On each computer (3) after getting anaconda installed,  I run `conda update conda` and `conda update anaconda`. Never had any problem.

Comment: @Celdor The restriction is that the server is behind firewall, so neither `conda install pyodbc` nor `conda update` works. I have to download the package installation file, upload it to the server via `scp` and install it locally. `conda` allows to do that based on its documentation. https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq#id6

Comment: Can you create a new virtualenv within Anaconda and then try `pip install /path/to/file` with this virtualenv? And make sure to remove everything related to `pyodbc` from the core packages. Looks like a broken installation.